# Video Codec Error

Tags: video, python, plugins, codecs

I have noticed on some videos that when I play some unusual video formats I always see this message. Can someone please give me instructions how to resolve this issue? Which codec do I need to install to get rid of this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for `ubuntu-restricted-extras` in the Software Center and then install it.

This installs all the non-free video decoders in ubuntu.  Since they are non-free, they are not included in the Ubuntu CD.

Comment: Yai did this in the very beginning but no use . It still pops up